# How to select more then 1 item in listbox in matlab GUI?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a problem with listbox in matlab gui. 
I need to select more then one item(option in the list).
Is there any possilitiy to select two items (second with ctrl) ?

I would appreciate for any help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list named `list_box`, then all you need to do is set min and max parameters.

```
set(list_box,'Max', 3, 'Min', 0);
```

Here, digit 3 indicates the maximum number of elements which can be selected, 0 - the minimum. And yes, another element can be selected by holding the ctrl key.